# Response is not available in this context

Tags: azure

This is what the exception I am getting while running an Web project which is migrated from Asp.net to Windows Azure Cloud. If I try to run the ASP.net application it is fine, but after migrating to Windows Azure Cloud I am getting the following exception. There is no clue for me to find a solution, please someon do the needful..

```
**Exception:**
Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException()
{"Response is not available in this context."}
    [System.Web.HttpException]: {"Response is not available in this context."}
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    HelpLink: null
    InnerException: null
    Message: "Response is not available in this context."
    Source: "System.Web"

    StackTrace: "   at System.Web.UI.Page.get_Response()\r\n   at Writehome_aspxToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , ClassDataContract )\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeAndVerifyType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean verifyKnownType, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithXsiType(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle objectTypeHandle, Type objectType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declare
dType)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContextComplex.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)\r\n   at WritePlaceHolderToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , ClassDataContract )\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.S
erializeAndVerifyType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean verifyKnownType, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithXsiType(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle objectTypeHandle, Type objectType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContextComplex.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)\r\n   at WriteArrayOfControlToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , Collection
DataContract )\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeAndVerifyType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean verifyKnownType, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithXsiType(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle objectTypeHandle, Type objectType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDec
laredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContextComplex.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)\r\n   at WriteArrayOfanyTypeToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , CollectionDataContract )\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithoutXsiType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)\r\n   a
t System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContextComplex.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)\r\n   at WriteSerializableSessionStateStoreDataToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , ClassDataContract )\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.NetDataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObjectContent(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContract contract, Hashtable surrogateDataContracts)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.NetDataContractSerializer.InternalWr
iteObject(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.InternalWriteObject(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObjectHandleExceptions(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)\r\n   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObject(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, Object graph)\r\n   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.NetDataContractCacheObjectSerializer.Serialize(Stream stream, Object value)\r\n   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheObjectSerializationProvider.SerializeUserObject(Object userObject, Boolean isCompressionEnabled, ValueFlagsVersion flagsType)\r\n   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.SocketClientProtocol.SerializeValue(Object obj)\r\n   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.SocketClientProtocol.PutAndUnlock(String key, Object value, DataCacheLockHandle lockHandle,
 TimeSpan timeout, DataCacheTag[] tags, String region, IMonitoringListener listener)\r\n   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCache.InternalPutAndUnlock(String key, Object value, DataCacheLockHandle lockHandle, TimeSpan timeout, DataCacheTag[] tags, String region, IMonitoringListener listener)\r\n   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCache.<>c__DisplayClass9c.<PutAndUnlock>b__9b()\r\n   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.MonitoringListenerFactory.EmptyListener.Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.IMonitoringListener.Listen[TResult](Func`1 innerDelegate)\r\n   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCache.PutAndUnlock(String key, Object value, DataCacheLockHandle lockHandle, TimeSpan timeout)\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DataCacheWrapper.PutAndUnlock(String key, Object value, DataCacheLockHandle lockHandle, TimeSpan timeout)\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DataCacheForwarderBase.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<PutAndUnlock>b__1b()\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DataCacheFo
rwarderBase.<>c__DisplayClass31`1.<PerformCacheOperation>b__30()\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DataCacheRetryWrapper.PerformCacheOperation(Action action)\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DataCacheForwarderBase.PerformCacheOperation[TResult](Func`1 func)\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DataCacheForwarderBase.PutAndUnlock(String key, Object value, DataCacheLockHandle lockHandle, TimeSpan timeout)\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.BlobBasedSessionStoreProvider.SetAndReleaseItemExclusive(HttpContextBase context, String id, SessionStateStoreData item, Object lockId, Boolean newItem)\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DistributedCacheSessionStateStoreProvider.SetAndReleaseItemExclusive(HttpContext context, String id, SessionStateStoreData item, Object lockId, Boolean newItem)\r\n   at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.OnReleaseState(Object source, EventArgs eventArgs)\r\n   at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Exec
ute()\r\n   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)"
    TargetSite: {System.Web.HttpResponse get_Response()}
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens if you try to do Azure stuff like accessing the blob in the `Application_Start` method.

It was because `HttpContext.Current.Response` was accessible.Azure uses the Response object for logging. In any case, if you need to access the blob in your web app or do any other Azure stuff AND want to do this even though there is not a Response object, like in the `Application_Start` method. You simply set `HttpContext.Current to null`, but in a smart way.

**Application_Start is as below**

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CloudStorageAccount.SetConfigurationSettingPublisher((configName, configSetter) =>
    {
        configSetter(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue(configName));
    });

    using (new AzureContext())
    {
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.FromConfigurationSetting("BlobConnectionString");

        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");
        container.CreateIfNotExist();
        container.FetchAttributes();
    }
}
```

**AzureContext is as below :**

```
public class AzureContext : IDisposable
{
    HttpContext _oldHttpContext;
    bool _restoreOldHttpContext = false;


    public AzureContext(bool forceSettingContextToNull = false)
    {
        if (forceSettingContextToNull)
        {
            _oldHttpContext = HttpContext.Current;
            HttpContext.Current = null;
            _restoreOldHttpContext = true;
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
            }
            catch (HttpException)
            {
                _oldHttpContext = HttpContext.Current;
                HttpContext.Current = null;
                _restoreOldHttpContext = true;
            }
        }
    }


    public void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (_restoreOldHttpContext)
            {
                HttpContext.Current = _oldHttpContext;
            }
        }
    }


    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
    }


    ~AzureContext()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }
}
```

For more information check this out [**Azure and Response is not available in this context**](http://toolheaven.net/post/Azure-and-Response-is-not-available-in-this-context.aspx)

I hope this will help to you.

Answer (score 0):

I suffered because of this issue... You can resolve this issue by applying this patch...

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2468871

I had applied this patch in my local environment and as well as in the cloud environment (using startup role). But you may not need to patch the cloud environment now because they might updated. You can contact Azure support( India : 1-(866) 676-6546) regarding this issue if the issues is still exist in the cloud, They will help you with applying the patch.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but after this update also the same error remains.

Comment: @Ilayapsv can you restart and check?

Comment: Yes I tried by restarting the PC iteself, but the same error remains. I noticed another point, when the sessionstate mode="Custom" is set in the web.config it is giving the error. But in the mode="InProc" it working fine..

Answer (score 0):

Thank for all your help, finnally i have found out the reason for the issue. Issue occured because I was trying to store the the System.Web.UI.WebControls into a session.

Since not all System.Web.UI.WebControls are serilizable, so avoid storind WebControls to session.

Happy coding..